# How to use object of type Promise <string | null> as a string

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-fullstack, micro-orm

hello guys I am having a problem with the types in typescript.
I am using micro orm to fetch data from the database I am using this code

```
const user = (await orm).em.findOne(User, { username: options.username });
```

it's returning me

```
user: Promise<string | null>
```

my problem starts here I have to use this object as a string  in the form

```
user.password
```

in following query

```
const valid = await argon2.verify(user.password ,options.password);
```

but its giving me error as

```
Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Promise<User | null>'
```

I have no idea  how to resolve this

Comment: Is your function returning `Promise<string | null>` or `Promise<User | null>` ? None of those have a property `password`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are already in an async function. The issue is that you are not waiting for the user promise to complete.

Try this:

```
// Check that this is really giving you an Entity Manager
const em = (await orm).em;

const users = await em.findOne(User, { username: options.username }); 
if (!users || users.length === 0) throw new Error('No user!');
const user = users[0];
const valid = await argon2.verify(user.password ,options.password);
```

Comment: Let me clarify - I'll edit the code a little

Comment: It worked Thanks a lot, bro you are doing great work keep it up.